# Почти полное бинарное дерево

Tags: дерево, бинарное-дерево, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы функция проходилась к примеру по всей левой части дерева?

Я сделал функцию проверки дерева на то, является ли оно почти полным, но при входе в левое поддерево, функция проверяет не всех потомков.. аналогичная проблема в правом поддереве

```
bool PBDPP1 (TNode* ptree, int &cnt)
{
    if (ptree != NULL)
    {   cnt++;
        if(ptree->right != 0 && ptree->left == 0)            
            return false;
        PBDPP1(ptree->left, cnt);
        PBDPP1(ptree->right, cnt);
    }
    else return true;
}

bool PPBD(TNode *rootTree)
{
    int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0;
    if(rootTree != NULL)
    {
       if(PBDPP1(rootTree->left, cnt2))
       {
          if(PBDPP1(rootTree->right, cnt1))
          {
              int res = cnt2 - cnt1;
              if(res >= 0)
                  return true;
              else
                  return false;
          }
       }
   }
   else return false;
}
```

Напомню, почти полным двоичным деревом называется двоичное дерево, для которого существует такое целое число h ≥ 0, что:

1. каждый лист в дереве имеет уровень h или h + 1
2. если узел дерева имеет правого потомка уровня h + 1, тогда все его левые потомки, являющиеся листами, также имеют уровень h + 1.

Comment: @Юра1996, Вы бы еще не заставляли лазить по сети и смотреть, а что же это такое -- *почти полное дерево*?

Интуитивно, наверное дерево у которого есть только листья и полностью заполненные узлы.

Тогда смотреть надо как-то так:

     bool ppdb (Node *p) {
       if (!p) return false;
       if (p->left && p->right)
          if (ppdb(p->left)) 
            return ppdb(p->right);
          else
            return false;
       if (p->left || p->right) // узел только с одним потомком
         return false;
       return true; // это лист, ни одного потомка
     }

Не проверял.

Comment: @avp, Почти полное бинарное дерево определяется как бинарное дерево, для которого существует неотрицательное целое k такое, что:

1)     каждый лист в дереве имеет уровень k или k+1;

2)     если узел дерева имеет правого потомка уровня k+1, тогда все его левые потомки, являющиеся листами, также имеют уровень k+1.

Comment: то есть, со слов преподавателя, это бинарное дерево, которое может существовать, если существует только левый потомок или оба. То есть если есть только правый потомок, то это уже не ППБД.

Comment: Плюс ко всему, следуя из условия 2, написанного выше, все листья должны иметь одинаковый уровень(если я правильно понимаю)

Comment: @avp, я предполагаю, что может быть так? хотя с виду я сделал какой-то бред...

    bool PPBD (TNode *rootTree) {
       if (!rootTree) return false;
       if (rootTree->left && rootTree->right)
          if (PPBD(rootTree->left))
            return PPBD(rootTree->right);
          else return false;
       if (rootTree->left && !rootTree->right){
          if(PPBD(rootTree->left))
             return true;}
       else
         return false;
       return true;
    }

Comment: Спасибо, за информацию. Что-то не очевидно сразу, как надо делать. Может подумаю на досуге.

Простой, но какой-то некрасивый (не нравится он что-то мне) вариант -- это пробежаться по самой левой ветке и запомнить глубину. Потом обходить дерево и в каждом листе сверяться с этой глубиной. В левом листе д.б. равна, в правом может быть на 1 меньше.

Может оказаться, что в узле надо заглядывать дальше и смотреть влево-вправо -- это лист или узел.

Не знаю, думать надо.

--

@Юра1996, Вы комментарии (свои мысли в них, т.е. для чего туда-сюда идете, что именно проверяете) не бойтесь писать.

Comment: Нее, @Юра1996, как я делал (и в Вашей модификации тоже) не пойдет.

Потому что, двигаясь только вот этим путем

      if(PPBD(rootTree->left))
         return true;

мы для вырожденного дерева (из одних левых потомков) вернем true.

--

Ладно, думайте, может еще кто-нибудь заинтересуется и что-то дельное посоветует. 


А я домой пошел.

Comment: Все равно, придумать ничего лучшего, чем посчитать уровень самого левого листа (в ходе в общем-то обычного обхода дерева) и танцевать от этого значения не получилось.

В принципе все не так и плохо, поскольку этот лист естественным образом оказывается первым из посещенных листьев.

В общем прототип внутренней функции (кстати, выяснил в wiki, что по Английски эта штука называется "almost complete binary tree") :

     bool acbt (Node *t, int level, int *maxlevel);

и я ее вызываю из 

     bool is_acbt (Node *t);

для левого и правого поддеревьев корня, после проверок самого корня на "acbt".

Answer (score 2):

Решение взято [от сюда](http://www.ritambhara.in/check-if-a-tree-is-almost-complete-binary-tree/).

Предлагается обходить дерево в ширину и на каждом шаге проверять условия:

1. если найден лист то все последующие узлы также листы
2. если узел имеет правого потомка, то он должен иметь и левого.

В коде вот так примерно:

```
bool IsAlmostComplete(TNode * root)
{
    std::queue<TNode *> nodes;
    nodes.push(root);

    bool leaf_found = false;
    while(!nodes.empty())
    {
         TNode * node = nodes.front(); 
         nodes.pop();

         if(leaf_found && (node->left || !node->right))
             return false;          // у автора true, думаю он ошибся

         if(!node->left && !node->right)
             leaf_found = true;

         if(node->left && !node->right)
             return false;

         if(node->left)
             nodes.push(node->left);

         if(node->right)
             nodes.push(node->right);
    }
    return true;
}
```